# html src regexp iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

Need some hints on this simple regexp.

### Regexp and target string code for extracting src from < img src="..." />

```
NSString *imgTag = @"<img alt=\"\" src=\"/sites/default/files/mypic.gif\" style=\"width: 300px; height: 195px;\" />";

NSRegularExpression *a = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"src=\"(.*)\"" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
```

Not sure if it has something to do with the `options`

```
NSTextCheckingResult *matches = [a firstMatchInString:imgTag options:NSMatchingReportProgress range:NSMakeRange(0, [imgTag length])];

NSRange matchRange = [matches range];
NSString *src = [imgTag substringWithRange:matchRange];
NSLog(@"%s, %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, src);
```

Now the output is unexpected since it returns not only the group, but also everything after it up to the end tag.

### Output

```
/sites/default/files/mypic.gif" style="width: 300px; height: 195px;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is basically matching everything from the first `"` to the last `"`.

You should probably use the non-greedy operator `?`, which "[Matches 0 or more times. Matches as few times as possible.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW49)".
E.g.:

```
NSRegularExpression *a = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"src=\"(.*?)\"" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is being greedy.

Try:

```
@"src=\"(.*?)\""
```

for your expression.